# Display selected variation price suffixed in Woocommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I am using this function so I get the default variation price but I want to show my price suffix after the price:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $pav){
        $def=true;
        foreach($product->get_variation_default_attributes() as $defkey=>$defval){
            if($pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey]!=$defval){
                $def=false;             
            }   
        }
        if($def){
            $price = $pav['display_price'];         
        }
    }   
    return woocommerce_price($price);
}
```

What I am getting out now is for example '€15,00' but what I want it to show is '€15,00 per kilo' and 'per kilo' is the price suffix

Comment: your question is unclear?what expected outcome you want? what output currently your getting? Please post all these in your question.

Comment: what do you mean by price suffix ?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Try `return woocommerce_price($price).' per kilo';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is outdated since Woocommerce 3 *(*`get_variation_default_attributes()` *and* `woocommerce_price()` *are deprecated)*.

The will display the selected variation price suffixed for Woocommerce 3:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'display_variation_price_suffixed', 10, 3 );
function display_variation_price_suffixed( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    $variation_data['price_html'] .= ' <span class="price-suffix">' . __("per kilo", "woocommerce") . '</span>';

    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If needed you can use `$variation_data['attributes']` array to target specific product attributes term values in a foreach loop.

For information, the filter hook [`woocommerce_available_variation`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Variable.html#300) is located inside [`WC_Product_Variable` `get_available_variation()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Variable.html#286-326) method.

Comment: If you don't make the "per kilo" hard coded, I'll give you a +1.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans My answer code just shows the correct hooked code to be used for Woocommerce Variable products since version 3. The OP asked in his comment for a "per kilo" prefix, so I don't catch your comment.

Comment: Don't be too strict. It's the perfect answer so +1 you'll have. What if they want in ounces, grams, ... It could have been a nice addition.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans Ok I see… but I am not sure that the OP want it dynamic from the global unit weight that you can set in Woocommerce…